# How can I make realpath never resolve symlinks?

Tags: files, filenames, symlink

I'm looking for a command to return the absolute path of a file, without resolving symlinks. In general, `realpath` does this well.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test; cd /tmp/test
$ mkdir foo
$ ln -s foo bar
$ realpath -se bar           # good, this does not resolve the symlink
/tmp/test/bar
```

It also works for files inside symlink directories.

```
$ touch foo/file
$ realpath -se bar/file      # good, this does not resolve the symlink
/tmp/test/bar/file
```

However, it fails when the current director *is* a symlink directory

```
$ cd bar
$ pwd
/tmp/test/bar
$ realpath -se file          # this fails, returning the target
/tmp/test/foo/file
$ realpath -se .             # this also fails, returning the target
/tmp/test/foo
$ realpath -se /tmp/test/bar/file # yet this works
/tmp/test/bar/file
$ realpath -se /tmp/test/bar # and this works
/tmp/test/bar
```

Why would `realpath` behave like that? (Is it a bug?) Is there a way to get `realpath` to never resolve the symlink, or is there another method I should use?

Comment: It seems as if `realpath`, when the given pathname is a filename, does a `pwd -P` (equivalent) to get the current directory path. Prepending `$PWD/` would be a solution, but an awkward one.

Comment: when you do `cd bar`, it's already too late: the shell is now in `/tmp/test/foo` and nothing run from it will be able to know about `bar`. The only thing still knowing about `bar` is the shell itself (built-in `pwd` but not `/bin/pwd`, `$PWD` and its output in `$PS1`). To tell it otherwise, try: `ls -l /proc/$$/cwd`.

Comment: @A.B Could you please explain in more detail? What do you mean by "the shell is now in"? Are you saying that apart from the exceptions you list, any other command is fed the target, and reads from `/proc/$$/cwd`?

Comment: I made an answer. I hope the explanation is ok to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current workind directory (CWD) of a process is inherited at the OS level from the previous process or it can be changed for the current process using `chdir(2)`. The OS (here I mean "the kernel") of course will always resolve any symlink to determine the end result which must be a directory, not a symlink (to a directory). For example the previous system call (`chdir(2)`) can return the error `ELOOP` when there were too many symbolic links to resolve. So from the OS point of view, there can't be a CWD not being a directory for any process: the OS will always resolve it the the real path without any symlink anywhere.

Once the shell has done `cd /tmp/test/bar`, the CWD path was resolved by the OS into `/tmp/test/foo`. For example, on a Linux system, `ls -l /proc/$$/cwd` will show the link to the resolved path as seen by the kernel: `/tmp/test/foo`.

The fact that the shell still displays `bar` in its prompt is that because it remembers the *cd* command done before. The behaviour could depend on the shell kind. I'll assume bash here. So its built-in `pwd` (but not the external `/bin/pwd` command), the `$PWD` variable and their use in `$PS1` will "lie" to the user about the current directory.

Any process, such as `realpath`, or `/bin/pwd` run from the shell will of course inherit the *actual* CWD, which is `/tmp/test/foo`. So that's not a bug in `realpath`, it will never have a specific information about `bar`.

One possible awkward way, as suggested by Kusalananda is to reuse somehow the `$PWD` variable and prepend it to `realpath`'s argument only if its argument isn't absolute already.

Here's an example. I'm not sure there are not ways to abuse it. For example, while the function below would cope, the `$PWD` variable itself doesn't behave well in bash 4.4.12 (Debian 9) but works fine in bash 5.0.3 (Debian 10) if there's a linefeed  character in the path. When there's a linefeed somewhere, to be useful, a `-z` option should also be added to `realpath` but I'm not going to reimplement the whole parsing of options in this simple example.

```
myrealpathnofollowsym () {
    for p in "$@"; do
        if ! printf '%s' "$p" | grep -q -- '^/'; then
            realpath -se "$PWD/$p"
        else
            realpath -se "$p"
        fi
    done
}
```